# Mathjax not working for me in chat

Tags: discussion, mathjax, chat

I've been in the chat "h-bar" physics stackexchange chat,  and somebody wrote  `$\frac{1}{2}$` and it comes up for me like those literal characters and not as $\frac{1}{2}$

Any idea why / how I can enable mathjax in chat?

The guy that posted it said he can see it and thought it might be an issue on my end.

I don't know if it's a bug of some sort, or perhaps i'm just missing an option.

Comment: You need a client-side extension for visualizing MathJax text. See [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97938/any-chance-of-mathjax-in-chat/220976#220976).

Answer (score 2):

MathJax does not work out-of-the-box on chat; the behaviour you observe is precisely as expected. To turn it on, you need to turn a client-side extension which is described in

- [Any chance of MathJax in chat?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97938/any-chance-of-mathjax-in-chat/220976#220976)

but the short of it is that to turn on [ChatJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1088/should-chat-have-tex-support/3297#3297), you can just drag-and-drop the link marked `start ChatJax` in [this page](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~robjohn/math/mathjax.html) up to your bookmarks bar, and then click the resulting bookmarklet to turn on mathjax in chat.

This is handily linked in the chatroom description, if you ever need it

> [image]

though indeed it's not the most discoverable text ever written.

Comment: I was tempted to name and shame people who pass judgement on visuals-driven films from just reading the screenplay, but apparently they are immune to it  ¯\ _(ツ)_/¯.

Comment: You are referring to me?

Comment: @JohnRennie possibly? =)

Comment: Seriously, though, you should watch it, just for the sheer joy of the visuals.