# Chat does not support LaTeX input

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, chat, mathjax

The chat does not show LaTeX, not even in the comments which were moved to chat and had working LaTeX in the comments section.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9789/2451

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enable it manually on the client side, see [this mother meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/220976/263383):

> - [**ChatJax**](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1088/should-chat-have-tex-support/3297#3297), a set of bookmarklets by [robjohn](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/users/13854/robjohn) to enable dynamic MathJax support in chat.  Commonly used in the [Mathematics chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics).
>
>   - An alternative [offshoot of ChatJax](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89/mathjax-in-chat-chatjax-offshoot) by [ManishEarth](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/users/22/manishearth), with support for the mhchem extension used to render chemical formulae.
> - [**Google Chrome Chat MathJax Extension**](https://stackapps.com/questions/4370/google-chrome-chat-mathjax-extension): exactly what it says on the tin.  Does more or less the same thing as ChatJax, but packaged as an Google Chrome extension.
> - [**ChatJax++**](https://github.com/vyznev/chatjax), a [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) (Firefox) / [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) (Chrome) user script.  Features individual rendering of new chat messages as they arrive, which should hopefully make it a bit faster and more CPU-friendly than the bookmarklet.  Still lacks some planned features, but basic functionality is present.  Requires [SOUP](https://github.com/vyznev/soup).  Supports mhchem in the Chemistry and Biology chat rooms.
> - A [**script version of ChatJax**](https://gist.github.com/bassup/93f78c0fac2a7be25086) for [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) (Firefox) / [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) (Chrome), which automatically enables MathJax rendering in all chat rooms. It has no external dependencies, so people who don't want to use SOUP for some reason might find this useful.